# Action of Galois on $L$-Schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, arithmetic-geometry

Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension and let $X$ be a projective $L$-variety. Then, for every $\sigma \in $ Gal$(L,K)$, we get a projective $L$-variety $X^\sigma$ obtained via the action of $\sigma$ on the coefficients of the polynomials defining $X$ (considering $X$ as embedded in some projective space).

Can one define an action of Gal$(L/K)$ on the set of $L$-schemes X such that this action agrees with the usual action on varieties?

Comment: um.. what ??? what set are you saying $G$ is acting on exactly ?

Comment: @mercio I meant to say "Gal$(L/K)$ acts on $X$" not "$L$ acts  on $X$". I've edited to fix that, not sure if that was causing confusion. The set I am saying Gal$(L/K)$ acts on is the set of all $L$-varieties. My question is whether one can similarly define an action on the set of $L$-schemes.

Comment: Yes, compose with the structure map to Spec L.